# Crashing while converting string to wstring

Tags: c++, regex, http

I got the following function that crashes randomly when converting a string to a wstring. It is used to parse HTTP headers (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C ) and always worked fine, but it randomly stopped working when I changed server recently. (This code comes from the classes that comes with the codeproject project)

```
inline bool ParseRegExpW(const wstring &regExp, bool caseSensitive, int groupCount, const wstring &source, vector<wstring> &result, bool allowDuplicate = false)
{
    const string regEXP = string(regExp.begin(), regExp.end());
    const string Source = string(source.begin(), source.end());
    vector<string> Result;
    if (result.size() != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Result[i] = string(result[i].begin(), result[i].end());
        }
    }
    bool res = ParseRegExp(regEXP, caseSensitive, groupCount, Source, Result, allowDuplicate);
    if (Result.size() != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < Result.size(); i++) {
            printf("Result: %i->%s L: %i : R %i r %i\n", i, Result[i].c_str(), Result[i].length(), Result.size(), result.size());//Result[i] contains what it should contain
            if (i < Result.size()){
                printf("Converting...\n");
                result[i] = wstring(Result[i].begin(), Result[i].end());
                printf("Will crash before getting there..\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Why is this happening? It's so weird to me that it was working fine for the last months and stopped working when I changed server.

Comment: `operator[]` does **not** insert any new elements into a `std::vector`. So if `result.size() != 0` this will crash, too.

Comment: `vector<string> Result;` creates a vector of zero size. You should use `Result.push_back()` instead of `Result[i]` when adding content.

Comment: Also, having both `result` and `Result` just begs for a typo or two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `result.size() == 0`, when you get into that loop and to ...

```
result[i] = wstring(Result[i].begin(), Result[i].end());
```

... then no matter the value of `i`, you'll get *undefined behavior* due to accessing a non-existent element of the vector.

If `result.size() != 0`, then this code path will be executed, ...

```
vector<string> Result;
if (result.size() != 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        Result[i] = string(result[i].begin(), result[i].end());
    }
}
```

... which has the same issues in regard to the empty vector `Result`.

I'm wondering how this could've ever worked.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I replaced both Result[i] & result[i] by push_back and it works fine. I'll go through the code of that WinHTTP wrapper I posted above tomorrow since just taking a quick look at it (Which I never did before since I didn't need to) shows alot of stuff that is weird.